# Problem minimizing a constrained function in Python with scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, numeric, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to minimize a constrained function of several variables adopting the algorithm `scipy.optimize.minimize`. The function concerns the minimization of `3*N` parameters, where `N`is an input. More specifically, my minimization parameters are given in three arrays `H = H[0],H[1],...,H[N-1]`, `a = a[0],a[1],...,a[N-1]` and `b = b[0],b[1],...,b[N-1]` which I concatenated in only one array named `mins`, with `len(mins)=3*N`.

Those parameters are also subjected to constraints as follows:

```
0 <= H  and  sum(H) = 0.5
0 <= a <= Pi/2
0 <= b <= Pi/2
```

So, my code for the constraints read as:

```
import numpy as np

# constraints on x:
def Hlhs(mins):    # left hand side
    return np.diag(np.ones(N)) @ mins.reshape(3,N)[0]
def Hrhs(mins):    # right hand side
    return np.sum(mins.reshape(3,N)[0]) - 0.5
con1H = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda H: Hlhs(H)}
con2H = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda H: Hrhs(H)}

# constraints on a:
def alhs(mins):
    return np.diag(np.ones(N)) @ mins.reshape(3,N)[1]
def arhs(mins): 
    return -np.diag(np.ones(N)) @ mins.reshape(3,N)[1] + (np.ones(N))*np.pi/2
con1a = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda a: alhs(a)}
con2a = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda a: arhs(a)}

# constraints on b:
def blhs(mins):
    return np.diag(np.ones(N)) @ mins.reshape(3,N)[2]
def brhs(mins): 
    return -np.diag(np.ones(N)) @ mins.reshape(3,N)[2] + (np.ones(N))*np.pi/2
con1b = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda b: blhs(b)}
con2b = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda b: brhs(b)}
```

My function, with the other parameters (and adopting `N=3`) to be minimized, is given by  (I'm sorry if it is too long):

```
gamma = 17      
C = 85         
T = 0         
Hf = 0.5         
Li = 2         
Bi = 1  
         
N = 3            

def FUN(mins):
    H, a, b = mins.reshape(3,N)
    S1 = 0; S2 = 0
    B = np.zeros(N); L = np.zeros(N);   
    for i in range(N):
        sbi=Bi; sli=Li
        for j in range(i+1):
            sbi += 2*H[j]*np.tan(b[j])
            sli += 2*H[j]*np.tan(a[j])
        B[i]=sbi
        L[i]=sli    
    for i in range(N):
        S1 += (C*(1-np.sin(a[i])) + T*np.sin(a[i])) * (Bi*H[i]+H[i]**2*np.tan(b[i]))/np.cos(a[i]) + \
        (C*(1-np.sin(b[i])) + T*np.sin(b[i])) * (Li*H[i]+H[i]**2*np.tan(a[i]))/np.cos(b[i])    
    S2 += (gamma*H[0]/12)*(Bi*Li + 4*(B[0]-H[0]*np.tan(b[0]))*(L[0]-H[0]*np.tan(a[0])) + B[0]*L[0])
    j=1 
    while j<(N):
        S2 += (gamma*H[j]/12)*(B[j-1]*L[j-1] + 4*(B[j]-H[j]*np.tan(b[j]))*(L[j]-H[j]*np.tan(a[j])) + B[j]*L[j])
        j += 1
    F = 2*(S1+S2)
    return F
```

And, finally, adopting an initial guess for the values as 0, the minimization is given by:

```
x0 = np.zeros(3*N)
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(FUN,x0,constraints=(con1H,con2H,con1a,con2a,con1b,con2b),tol=1e-25)
```

My problems are:

a) Observing the result `res`, some values got negative even though I have constraints for them to be positive. The success of the minimization was `False`, and the message was: `Positive directional derivative for linesearch`. Also, the result is very far from the minimum expected.

b) Adopting the `method='trust-constr'` I got a value closer to what I was expecting but with a false success and the message `The maximum number of function evaluations is exceeded.`. Is there any way to improve this?

I know that there is a minimum very close to these values:

```
H = [0.2,0.15,0.15]
a = [1.0053,1.0053,1.2566]
b = [1.0681,1.1310,1.3195]
```

where the value for the function is `123,45`. I've checked the function several times and it seems to be working properly. Can anyone help me to find where my problem is? I've tried to change `xtol` and `maxiter` but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few hints:

- Your initial point `x0` is not feasible since it doesn't satisfy the constraint `sum(H) = 0.5`. Providing a feasible initial point should fix your first problem.
- Except for the constraint `sum(H) = 0.5`, all constraints are simple bounds on the variables. In general, it's recommended to pass variable bounds via the `bounds` parameter of `minimize`. You can simply define and pass all the bounds like this

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

# ..your variables and functions ..

bounds = [(0, None)]*N + [(0, np.pi/2)]*2*N

x0 = np.zeros(3*N)
x0[0] = 0.5

res = minimize(FUN, x0, constraints=(con2H,), bounds=bounds,
               method="trust-constr", options={'maxiter': 20000})
```

where each tuple contains the lower and upper bound for each variable.

- Unfortunately, 'trust-constr' has still trouble to converge to a local minimizer. In this case, you can either try other initial points or you can use the state-of-the-art open source solver Ipopt instead. The Cython wrapper [cyipopt](https://github.com/mechmotum/cyipopt) provides a interface similar to scipy:

```
from cyipopt import minimize_ipopt

# rest as above

res = minimize_ipopt(FUN, x0, constraints=(con2H,), bounds=bounds)
```

this gives me a solution with objective value 122.9.

- Last but not least, it's always a good idea to provide exact gradients, jacobians and hessians.